# Error running regasm in Windows XP on Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm trying to install an old application on 32-bit Windows XP.  XP is a guest OS running on a Windows 10 x64 host OS via Oracle Virtual Box.

Part of the installation instructions are to install some .dll drivers manually via regasm, gacutil, etc.

When I try to run regasm on the host os it's giving me the following error:

```
The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000135)
```

The regasm that I'm running is in the files distributed in the software I'm trying to install.  I'm wondering if it's corrupt, if it's a problem inherent with running on Oracle Virtual Box, or what.

I get the error both when I run regasm with no parameters and when I run it to register a tlb like so:

```
regasm %WINDIR%\system32\MyDLL.dll /tlb:%WINDIR%\system32\MyDLL.tlb
```

Thanks

Comment: 0xc0000135 can be  STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND or ERROR_NOTIFICATION_GUID_ALREADY_DEFINED (The specified file already has a notification GUID associated with it.)

Comment: I added some more information to my post.  I'm getting this both when running regasm with no parameters and to register a tlb.  Where did you get the statuses you put in your comment?

Comment: I used the tool err.exe from Win7 SDK.